# Update existing values in a table from related fields on different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very unique and strange task. I have a Postgres database that is not properly normalized, where data is repeating outside of foreign keys.

I need to fill all fields where data is missing. I need to grab the data from the related fields from other tables.

Tables below mirror the database:

**What I Need**

- In the [VIS] need to fill row 1 with the value from [DTA] 1.
- In [DTA] row 2 I need to fill with the value from [VIS] 2.
- In [CRT] I need row 3 to equal the higher timestamp which is in [VIS] 3, Row 1 & 2 also need the previous highest (MAX) values calculated before in the previous tables

**Restrictions**

- Can only be done using pgSQL statements
- No stored procedures
- Multiple consecutive statements are fine

**Considerations**

- I actually have 6 tables not 3 that I have to deal with
- I have 2 fields Created and Updated date to deal with

**[ VIS ]**

| ID | Created Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -infinity |
| 2 | 2020-10-01 |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 |

**[ DTA ]**

| ID | Created Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-03 |
| 2 | -infinity |
| 3 | 2000-10-23 |

**[CRT]**

| ID | Created Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -infinity |
| 2 | -infinity |
| 3 | -infinity |

Would love any help or advice that you could give to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This query provides the correct dates based on your rules. Th elogic in `case`statements should be *self explained*. Adjust if required.

Also you'll need to use *outer* joins if your `id`'s are not complete in all tables.

```
select 
 crt.id,
 case when crt.created_date = '-infinity'::date then greatest(vis.created_date,dta.created_date) else crt.created_date end as crt_created_date,
 case when dta.created_date = '-infinity'::date then vis.created_date else dta.created_date end as dta_created_date,
 case when vis.created_date = '-infinity'::date then dta.created_date else vis.created_date end as vis_created_date
from crt
join dta on crt.id = dta.id
join vis on crt.id = vis.id

id|crt_created_date|dta_created_date|vis_created_date|
--+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 1|      2021-02-03|      2021-02-03|      2021-02-03|
 2|      2020-10-01|      2020-10-01|      2020-10-01|
 3|      2023-12-01|      2000-10-23|      2023-12-01|
```

Use the above query direct in the `update` statement - here the update for `vis`- adapt for the rest of tables

```
with fix as (
select 
 crt.id,
 case when crt.created_date = '-infinity'::date then greatest(vis.created_date,dta.created_date) else crt.created_date end as crt_created_date,
 case when dta.created_date = '-infinity'::date then vis.created_date else dta.created_date end as dta_created_date,
 case when vis.created_date = '-infinity'::date then dta.created_date else vis.created_date end as vis_created_date
from crt
join dta on crt.id = dta.id
join vis on crt.id = vis.id
)
update vis 
set created_date = vis_created_date
from fix
where vis.id = fix.id and vis.created_date = '-infinity'::date;

select * from vis order by id;

id|created_date|
--+------------+
 1|  2021-02-03|
 2|  2020-10-01|
 3|  2023-12-01|
```